# @PostConstruct and "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have to do some database stuff in my repository' `@PostConstruct`:

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepositoryHibernate implements SomeRepository {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SomeRepositoryHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomestuffWithDb() {
        ...
    }

}
```

but it fails with:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and 
   configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

is there any easy solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) what is your container -- it matters because different containers handle PostConstruct at different times (spring i'm assuming given the presence of an @Autowired notation).  2) What are you actually doing in your "doSomestuffWithDB" and how are your initializing your sessionFactory, which will also influence what youc an do with it at that point in time in the lifecycle.

Comment: 1) I currently run it on Jetty - haven't test on others. 2) I just can't get Hibernate session - sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), so can do nothing. thanks

Comment: My session is just <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

Comment: doesn't my answer shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 2):

- You don't have a running transaction in `@PostConstruct`
- you can't use `@Transactional` there (except for `mode="aspectj"`), so spring can't start the transaction
- a transaction is required for hibernate to mutate data (insert/update/delete)

So, you would have to create your session from the session factory (via `.openSession()`) there and start a transaction manually.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using hibernate combining with spring and you have configured your sessionFactory and transaction manager correctly in your spring config file.
Then the root cause is that when your doSomestuffWithDb() method is invoked the transaction prepare work has not been finished by spring. The @postconstruct can only ensure the method is called after the bean is created, it can not ensure the container is ready for everything- here, I mean the transaction related stuff- at the moment.
There is a detailed discussion in spring forum.
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58337-No-transaction-in-transactional-service-called-from-PostConstruct
Also, the author submitted his solution to jira at
[https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5966?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5966?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs)