# Spring, @PostConstruct, transactions...and will anything bad happen w/this workaround?

Tags: spring, hibernate

From some searching of prior questions I've seen that I can't expect to have a Hibernate session available to me in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`I've seen solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635147/617188) which suggest just creating your own session from the session factory something like this:

```
getSession().getSessionFactory().openSession()
```

This works like a charm for me, but it feels a little...off...are there any potential pitfalls I ought to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring manages your Hibernate `Session`s bounding one for every thread.

> I can't expect to have a Hibernate session available to me in a method
>   annotated with @PostConstruct

That is false, you can have a Session in that point.

You can do this in many ways, one is to define a bean of Session and telling Spring to instantiate it by the factory method "openSession" of your  SessionFactory bean. Something like this:

```
<!-- Prototype so there is a new Session in every injection -->
    <bean id="newSession" scope="prototype" class="...Session" factory-bean="sessionFactory"
        factory-method="openSession" ... >
    </bean>
```

Also you may want to tell Spring to use Hibernate managed Sessions through the Spring SessionFactory implementation.